# MONGO : Tough find() query, good explanation provided

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image]

What i have :

1. list of company names : [bmw, tata, ferrari,...]
2. transmission : Manual or Automatic3.
3. car color :   Red or White etc
4. model year : 2010 to 2014
5. Min Price  & Max Price. --> Price range

**===========================================================================**

What i can do now : if i had only one object (ie. one company in `companies`) then i would do something like :

```
query = {{transmission_type : transmission}, {color : car_color}, {year : model_year}, { $range: [ 0, "$PriceInINR", 25 ] }  }
```

`db.companies.cars.find(query)`

**But**  here first there are a lot of companies, and then each company has list of cars.

**How can i do such a query**.

1. I want a one query which considers the price range.
2. and Another with no price range condition.

*Early thoughts* : I thought that i could do query each company separately as i know company names. so finding the result individually and then push the to an array.

**How should i do this, any other suggestions?**

**===========================================================================**

psudo structure of `companies` collection

```
Companies {
    bmw: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },car3 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
        ],

    jaguar: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
          ],
    ferrari [
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --} 
        ]   
}
```

**===========================================================================**
Actual structure of `companies` collection in mongo db

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b78cc390cca71aa0e5"),
        "company_location" : "USA",
        "company_name" : "buick",
        "__v" : 0,
        "cars" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de56"),
                        "model" : "ENCLAVE",
                        "year" : 2014,
                        "PriceInINR" : 2537993,
                        "trim" : "Leather FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Silver",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de5d"),
                        "model" : "LaCrosse",
                        "year" : 2011,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4677427,
                        "trim" : "CXL FWD",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Grey",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b7d1a7c2156417de8e"),
                        "model" : "ENCORE",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4808616,
                        "trim" : "Leather FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "1.4L L4 DOHC 16V TURBO",
                        "color" : "Yellow",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b7d1a7c2156417dece"),
                        "model" : "LaCrosse",
                        "year" : 2011,
                        "PriceInINR" : 868875,
                        "trim" : "CXL FWD",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V",
                        "color" : "Grey",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b65a"),
                        "model" : "VERANO",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 4380113,
                        "trim" : "Base",
                        "engine" : "SEDAN 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V FFV",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b78cc390cca71aa0e7"),
        "company_location" : "USA",
        "company_name" : "gmc",
        "__v" : 0,
        "cars" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de57"),
                        "model" : "TERRAIN",
                        "year" : 2013,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3851710,
                        "trim" : "SLE2 FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "2.4L L4 DOHC 16V FFV",
                        "color" : "Yellow",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef8b6d1a7c2156417de5b"),
                        "model" : "YUKON",
                        "year" : 2015,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3129397,
                        "trim" : "SLE 2WD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "5.3L V8 OHV 16V",
                        "color" : "Silver",
                        "transmission_type" : "Manual",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },            
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b659"),
                        "model" : "SIERRA 1500",
                        "year" : 2014,
                        "PriceInINR" : 3649025,
                        "trim" : "SLE Crew Cab 2WD",
                        "engine" : "CREW CAB PICKUP 4-DR",
                        "body" : "5.3L V8 OHV 16V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b666"),
                        "model" : "TERRAIN",
                        "year" : 2012,
                        "PriceInINR" : 1896832,
                        "trim" : "SLT1 FWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.0L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b8ef9c1f0412315aa07b650"),
                        "model" : "ACADIA",
                        "year" : 2012,
                        "PriceInINR" : 2541355,
                        "trim" : "Denali AWD",
                        "engine" : "SPORT UTILITY 4-DR",
                        "body" : "3.6L V6 DOHC 24V",
                        "color" : "Metallic White",
                        "transmission_type" : "Automatic",
                        "dealer_id" : "5b8ee03ffe42df0d94de785d"
                }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your data and desired query I'd suggest something like this:

```
// I've tried to annotate without being too verbose
db.companies.aggregate([
  { $match: { company_name: { $in: [...] } } }, // match company names
  { $unwind: "$cars" },                         // separate cars array into distinct documents
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$cars" } },       // remove company information so it just has car information
  {
    $match: {                                   // match car information
      transmission_type: "",                    // any one of these can be omitted
      color: "",
      year: 0,
      PriceInINR: { $gt: 0, $lt: 0 }
    }
  }
])
```

On a side note, I find your data structure very strange. Typically you'd want to avoid nested arrays of objects, especially if you are going to do many queries on them.

Comment: its giving error, i removed the extra `}` but then also,  **https://imgur.com/a/klMyc2u**,     i did this structure thinking of it would decrease the no of cars that would be needed to search, eg. if i have suppose 50 companies and each of them have 5000 cars, so if i am having  different collections for both cars and companies then i would need to search the cars from all the cars that will be 50 * 5000 cars, NOW, if i relate all the cars with their respective company then i only need to search cars in that company ie only 5000 cars.. this was my approach do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: updated the query, the parenthesis' are right, but was missing $s

Comment: Its the same amount of data so that doesn't really affect the database in that regard. Having the appropriate indexes set up would reduce the 50*5000 problem. In this situation, you'd have individual cars that would have their company_id and you'd use that when searching for cars... if there's an index on company_id it can search through the index first and not have to look at *all* the cars. I say you should split up your documents because you're making it difficult on yourself in the long run whenever you want to manipulate cars, sometimes you don't always want to go through companies first.

Comment: if you wanted to get cars based on their dealer_id, you'd have to go through the same aggregation as above (which isn't particularly friendly to the database) to get what you want. If cars were their own collection, it'd be much nicer to query for...

Comment: You are right, thanks for the suggestion, i did this cause i don't know much monog, i have studie only the rdbms so its in habit to find a relations, here we can't implement the relation, so i took this approach, **specially** i can't go to car's directly i would need to go through companies and i am facing this already.. **THANKS for the suggestion** i would change it someday

Comment: where's the `{` before the last match going?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ogH67hX   i tried matching each braces **see something is wrong**

Comment: please look carefully at what I posted, there is a `{` between the line for `$replaceRoot` and the second `$match`... each stage of the aggregation is an object, so `$match` must have `{` before it

Comment: oh sorry, don't know how did i missed that

Comment: Its taking too much time : i don't know what is wrong it has got stuck, it doesn't even take 1 sec to print all the data (.. at this point data is very small) https://imgur.com/a/VX4lFbY

Comment: now you've removed a `}` from the first `$match`. its not running the query, its waiting for you to type more since you're missing the it

Comment: i am really sorry man, i don't know what i am doing today, : {

Comment: hey, command does execute, but no output   **see this **https://pastebin.com/58NjjSki

Comment: looks like I put `price` in my answer but your actual field is `PriceInINR`, apologies

Comment: yeah, thanks for the help, i was stupid i was just copy pasting, i didn't even cross check it. it working now thanks